# How to initiate an android app from a java web application?

Tags: android

I'm having a requirement as follows:

There is a web application which does some processing work and final agreement doc has to be displayed on an android device for the customer and accept his digital signature. How do I display the document on the device?  Is there any way to activate android app remotely?

Answer (score 1):

1. Develop your Android app that can take a digital signature and attach it to a document.
2. Make your customer install it on his/her Android device.
3. Use a service like [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to remotely start your app, and then have the app read the file off the server.
4. Have your customer sign.
5. Send the signed file back

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! but the situation is that app will not be distributed to customers, its like store representative approves the customer and once `approve` button is clicked on web app, the agreement doc has to popup on android screen.

Comment: @AnilM Then you can't do it via an Android app. You will have to build a browser based solution that can run within your web app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) (Google Cloud Messaging) to activate your app remotely, there is an open source app (by Google) called [Chrome to phone](https://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/checkout), which opens a website by pressing a button in the browser, you should check it out, I bet with minor modification you could adpot it to your needs

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I would check the feasibility!!